# TypeScript - set Type for decorated Object as function parameter

Tags: typescript

I have the following, very very contrived, example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-nobel-xv0ss?file=/src/index.ts

```
const barFunc = (ctx: any) => {
  const bar = ctx.bar;
  console.log(bar);
  ctx.baz = "baz";
  return ctx;
};

const fooFunc = (ctx: any) => {
  const foo = ctx.foo;
  const baz = ctx.baz;
  console.log(foo, baz);
  return ctx;
};

const funcs = {
  foo: fooFunc,
  bar: barFunc
};

const ctx = {
  foo: "foo",
  bar: "bar"
};

const b = funcs.bar;
b(ctx);

const f = funcs.foo;
f(ctx);
```

Inside `fooFunc` it would be nice to know that `baz` exists on `ctx`, how do I go about this?

And in general, how does one set a function parameter Type, ie. `ctx`, when the Object is being dynamically decorated by a previous function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you just use an interface instead of an `any` type?
i.e.

```
interface IHazBaz {
  baz: string;
}
interface IHazBar extends IHazBaz {
  bar: string;
}
interface IHazFoo extends IHazBaz {
  foo: string;
}

const barFunc = (ctx: IHazBar) => {
  const bar = ctx.bar;
  console.log(bar);
  ctx.baz = "baz";
  return ctx;
};

const fooFunc = (ctx: IHazFoo) => {
  const foo = ctx.foo;
  const baz = ctx.baz;
  console.log(foo, baz);
  return ctx;
};

const funcs = {
  foo: fooFunc,
  bar: barFunc
};

const ctx = {
  foo: "foo",
  bar: "bar"
};

const b = funcs.bar;
b(ctx); // type error

const f = funcs.foo;
f(ctx); // type error
```

This should protect from calling the function with an input that is missing parameters that are required by the function. Not sure if this is what you are after.

Comment: Yes, but `IHasBaz` doesn't have all the other properties that `ctx` ends up having?

Comment: interfaces can be extended too. So `interface IHazFoo extends IHazBaz { foo: string}`, would have 2 properties.